# Windows XP could not load installer for volume (HDD)

Tags: windows-xp, external-hard-drive

I bought a new external hard drive (WD Elements Portable); after plugging it into my Windows XP SP3 machine (a Dell Vostro 1015), the following message pops up:

> Windows could not load the installer for volume. Contact your hardware vendor for assistance.

The hard drive works without any problems on a Windows XP SP2 and Windows 7 machine.

Any thoughts how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `C:\Windows\System32` and rename `sfcfiles.dll` to `sfcfiles.old`. Next try copying the `sfcfiles.dll` file from `C:\Windows\ServicePackFiles\i386` to `C:\Windows\System32`.

The one in that folder should be the latest version, but if that doesn't work, do a `dir sfcfiles.dll /s` from a Command Prompt in the C: drive root to find other versions. This worked for a number of people in this thread:

> http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f10/windows-could-not-load-installer-33993.html

Comment: There was no sfcfiles.dll in system32 at all, so coped from C:\windows\ServicePackFiles\i386 and hdd mounted! Thanks :)